# Type Error when Randomize Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

I was making a simple flash card program to build my vocabulary, and thus needed to randomize a dictionay
I found many helpful answers on this site, many off this site, and noticed that shuffle was an option (i know there was random.choice, but i went with shuffle) but there's something that I'm not grasping.  looks like this:

```
import random

vocab_dict = {'word1':'def1',
           'word2':'def2',
           'etc.':'etc.'}

vocab_dict_rand = vocab_dict.keys()  
random.shuffle(vocab_rand)           **#<--This is where problem occurs**

for key in vocab_rand:
      print word
      input ""
      print definition
      input ""

input exit
```

So the program crashes and points to that line with the random.shuffle(vocab_rand)...

I get this in the shell

```
  File "C:\Python31\lib\random.py", line 270, in shuffle
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You overwrote the formatting edits saved before your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `dict.keys()` returns a special `dict_keys` object that only acts like a list -- it's not a real list, so you can't index into it or shuffle it (it should be used only for iteration).

Instead, use `vocab_rand = list(vocab_dict.keys())`.

Comment: wow... that was enlightening.  So i take it the TypeError was that the dictionary needed to be duplicated into a list form.  Was this not an issue in earlier versions?  Thanks a ton.

Comment: In earlier versions, `dict.keys()` returned a list. However, it seems to have been very frequently for iteration (for which producing the whole list is inefficient). In Python 3, they changed it to produce an iterator (actually a special object supporting the iteration protocol). This is in keeping with changes to several other builtin functions, like `range`, `map`, or `zip`, which all return iterators in Python3, but which produced lists in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `keys` returns an iterator, not a list.  You need to have a list to shuffle.  Use `vocab_dict_rand = list(vocab_dict.keys())`.